# Centos my.cfg file is incomplete

Tags: centos, mysql

I recently got a server which has mysql running and I want to access to it remotely. I searched internet and I find out that my.cfg file in /etc/ location has a property that will enable that:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

I should change the value of bind address and it should work!
But when I open my.cfg this is the content:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

and I can't seem to find where is the rest of these settings?
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's it. That is the minimal MySQL config file.

Check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-configuration-defaults.html) link to the MySQL site, it gives config details & info on as to other (more complete) config file you may have installed and Section 5.1 in general is all about config and the options/directives you can use. Please check and ensure you use the correct version of the site for your version of MySQL as there are a number of differences these days.